Как сделать такую grid сетку?
Как сделать такую грид сетку, чтобы при добавлении еще контента последующие вставали также?


В поисковике вбивайте javascript jquery masonry

Конечно я увидел, что нужно через grid, но как вариант можно использовать flex для такого шаблона. Если у вас идёт так - 3 изображения в ряд, потом 4 и так до бесконечности, то можно реализовать это так - для контейнера display:flex,flex-flow:wrap, для изображений через n выставить ширину в процентах и получится тот же результат, что и на фото. Если есть возможность выстроить изображения не в одном потоке, то можно создать 2 класса, где в одном будет сетка из 3 элементов, а в другом из 4, и будете в цикле их чередовать при выводе, но как по мне это более колхозно и громоздко.

Потом по клику на кнопку еще добавляются карточки flex не подходит

@Майя вы карточки добавляете в тот же поток изображений, всё будет дальше строиться так как вы пропишите - 3 потом 4, потом снова 3. А в контейнере у вас будут лежать все изображения на одном уровне с одним родителем, если нужно. могу оформить, как ответ - для наглядности.

Была бы признательная, если сделатете наглядно



#x{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 20vh;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: gray;
}

#x > *{
  background: brown;
  border: 2px solid skyblue;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  display: list-item;
  list-style: decimal inside;
}

#x > *:nth-child(7n),
#x > *:nth-child(7n-1),
#x > *:nth-child(7n-2),
#x > *:nth-child(7n-3)
{
  color: violet;
  grid-column: span 3;
}

#x > *:nth-child(7n-4),
#x > *:nth-child(7n-5),
#x > *:nth-child(7n-6)
{
  color: antiquewhite;
  grid-column: span 4;
}
<div id='x' data-comment='то самое чувство, когда увидел интересную задачку и от счастья
наложил кирпичей :3'>
  <hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>
  <hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>
  <hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>
</div>




Огромное спасибо))

Гений! А я подумал, подумал и плюнул на эту задачу)
